# Firing a Keyboard Event in Safari, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, dom-events, keyboard-events

I'm trying to simulate a keyboard event in Safari using JavaScript.

I have tried this:

```
var event = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
event.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 115, 0);
```

...and also this:

```
var event = document.createEvent("UIEvents");
event.initUIEvent("keypress", true, true, window, 1);
event.keyCode = 115;
```

After trying both approaches, however, I have the same problem: after the code has been executed, the `keyCode`/`which` properties of the event object are set to `0`, not `115`.

Does anyone know how to reliably create and dispatch a keyboard event in Safari? (I'd prefer to achieve it in plain JavaScript if possible.)

Comment: Are you trying to execute code you have defined or some key-combination the browser understands? If it's your own code, it might be best to setup an event wrapper that you can either call via a "real" keyboard interface or via some other event generator, as you have described here. Refactoring as appropriate.

Comment: In this example, I'm trying to simulate the user pressing "s". Ultimately, I'm trying to simulate the user pressing Command-R in an Apple Dashboard Widget.

Comment: Your code solved my problem :)

Comment: This might be helpful: [jquery.keymasher](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.keymasher).

Comment: Duplicate of [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Comment: According to the **[spec.](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#interface-keyboardevent)**, only `key` and `code` are supported.

Comment: To those voting to close this question. It doesn't not make sense to close this question, when the other question does not have an accepted answer and this question is specific to Safari. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/24177623)

Answer (score 44):

I am working on [DOM Keyboard Event Level 3 polyfill](https://github.com/termi/DOM-Keyboard-Event-Level-3-polyfill) . In latest browsers or with this polyfill you can do something like this:

```
element.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){ console.log(e.key, e.char, e.keyCode) })

var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {bubbles : true, cancelable : true, key : "Q", char : "Q", shiftKey : true});
element.dispatchEvent(e);

//If you need legacy property "keyCode"
// Note: In some browsers you can't overwrite "keyCode" property. (At least in Safari)
delete e.keyCode;
Object.defineProperty(e, "keyCode", {"value" : 666})
```

UPDATE:

Now my polyfill supports legacy properties "keyCode", "charCode" and "which"

```
var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    bubbles : true,
    cancelable : true,
    char : "Q",
    key : "q",
    shiftKey : true,
    keyCode : 81
});
```

Examples [here](http://jsfiddle.net/termi/yjc5F/)

Additionally here is cross-browser initKeyboardEvent separately from my polyfill: [(gist)](https://gist.github.com/4654819/)

Polyfill [demo](http://h123.ru/-/tests/KeyboardEvent)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for making a scrollable area scroll down using arrow or page up/down keys...

Comment: Changed your jsfiddle to dispatch the event on textbox instead of document @ http://jsfiddle.net/vnathalye/yjc5F/974/. Though it fires the keypress handler, the text doesn't get displayed in textbox. Any idea?

Comment: @termi Your demo link is dead

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for changing the value of an input (text) element either.

Comment: The operand of a delete operator cannot be a read-only property.

Answer (score 31):

Did you dispatch the event correctly?

```
function simulateKeyEvent(character) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
  (evt.initKeyEvent || evt.initKeyboardEvent)("keypress", true, true, window,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, character.charCodeAt(0)) 
  var canceled = !body.dispatchEvent(evt);
  if(canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}
```

If you use jQuery, you could do:

```
function simulateKeyPress(character) {
  jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : character.charCodeAt(0) });
}
```

Comment: Seems to be there's a mistake in the line: `evt.initKeyEvent`. In Chromium I don't have method initKeyEvent in KeyboardEvent.prototype. For me it has to be: `evt.initKeyboardEvent`

Comment: Is it possible to simulate control + C (copy shortcut) with this?

Comment: @EdPichler There is a special API for interacting with the pasteboard, I would't do it the hard way by simulating a keyboard event. [Related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @tarun-chaudhry did you mean: `(evt.initKeyEvent || evt.initKeyboardEvent).call(evt, // etc.` I'd preserve the context of the method invocation, just in case methods are using `this` internally...

Comment: @claudiopro Yes, you are correct it should be `(evt.initKeyEvent || evt.initKeyboardEvent).call(evt, // etc.`

Comment: The initKeyboardEvent doesn't work in Chromium either. `event.keyCode` and `event.which`always return 0. It's a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327853) and the workaround is to use a regular event `var event = document.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('keydown', true, true);
event.keyCode = 76;`

Comment: whatever you do, don't paste that code into typescript

Comment: **Downvoted**: `initKeyEvent` and `initKeyboardEvent` are **DEPRECATED**.

Comment: @K._ instead of downvoting for a previously functioning answer, stating that it's deprecated should be sufficient to give everyone a heads-up without negatively affecting tyronegcarter. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript/5920206#answer-11885974 uses the modern KeyboardEvent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Comment: @bit-less You're right. I didn't have to capitalize and highlight everything in bold. I feel I was overstepping a bit. That being said, I believe this is how the voting system works. Downvoting does not mean to be a total evil to someone, but to tell him what can get better in his question or answer and let the best answers at the moment float up.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at simulateKeyEvent (<anonymous>:3:46)`

Comment: Note that since posting this answer, the way to init an event has changed in favour of the much more sensible "passing the values into the constructor" so it's just `document.dispatchEvent(new Keyboard(`keypress`, { options : here }));` now.

Answer (score 18):

This is due to a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735) in Webkit.

You can work around the Webkit bug using `createEvent('Event')` rather than `createEvent('KeyboardEvent')`, and then assigning the `keyCode` property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522752/52207) and [this example](http://jsbin.com/awenaq/3).

Answer (score 9):

The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyEvent) provides the following explanation:

1. Create an event using `event = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent")`
2. Init the keyevent

using:

```
event.initKeyEvent (type, bubbles, cancelable, viewArg, 
       ctrlKeyArg, altKeyArg, shiftKeyArg, metaKeyArg, 
           keyCodeArg, charCodeArg)
```

3. [Dispatch the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) using `yourElement.dispatchEvent(event)`

I don't see the last one in your code, maybe that's what you're missing. I hope this works in IE as well...

Comment: Unfortunately, Mozilla's implementation is non-standard. As for point 3, my problem is creating the correct event—dispatching the event comes after this. Also, since I'm developing for Apple's Dashboard, I don't have to worry about IE at all! (Whoopee!)

Comment: `.initKeyEvent` is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I am not very good with this but `KeyboardEvent` => see [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)
 is initialized with `initKeyEvent` .
Here is an example for emitting event on `<input type="text" />` element

```js
document.getElementById("txbox").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  alert("Event " + e.type + " emitted!\nKey / Char Code: " + e.keyCode + " / " + e.charCode);
}, false);

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var doc = document.getElementById("txbox");
  var kEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
  kEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 74, 74);
  doc.dispatchEvent(kEvent);
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="txbox" type="text" value="" />
<input id="btn" type="button" value="CLICK TO EMIT KEYPRESS ON TEXTBOX" />
```

Comment: it shows `js:21TypeError: kEvent.initKeyEvent is not a function. (In 'kEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 74, 74)', 'kEvent.initKeyEvent' is undefined)` in safari :(

Comment: It should be:
var kEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent"); 
kEvent.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 74, 74);
  document.dispatchEvent(kEvent);