# HTML elements: How can I simulate pressing the 'tab' key

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, focus, element

I want to trigger the same effect than when pressing the tab key on an element that has the focus. Is there any way of doing this? I am trying to make the focus jump to the next element.

Thanks!

(jQuery is an option)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803338/simulate-the-tab-key-function-in-javascript

Comment: DanC, have you found a solution for the issue? I have the same task.

Stephen P, this is not a duplicate, there are situations when it's too hard to find the next active element on a page that should be focused.

Comment: Stephen P, no, I didn't find an answer. I restructured my code so that it would more or less do the job, but I couldn't simulate the effect of pressing the tab key.

Comment: @whitered: added a new answer that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (with jQuery):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

        <head>

            <title>LOL Focus!</title>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        </head>

        <form>
          <input class="focusable" type="text" value="lol"/>
          <input class="focusable" type="text" value="lol" />
          <input class="focusable" type="text" value="lol" />
          <input class="focusable" type="text" value="lol" />
          <input class="focusable" type="text" value="lol" />
          <input class="focusable" type="text" value="lol" />                 
        </form> 

        <input type="button" id="trigger_button" value="lol" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

          var focusable = $('.focusable'),
              last_element_index = focusable.length - 1,
              current_index;

          focusable.each(function(i) {
            $(this).click(function() {
              current_index = i;
            })
          });

           $('#trigger_button').click(function() {
             current_index = (should_reset_current_index()) ? 0 : current_index + 1;
             focusable[current_index].focus();
           });

           function should_reset_current_index() {
             return (typeof(current_index) === 'undefined') || (current_index == last_element_index)
           }

        });
      </script>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to emulate the tab functionality a while ago, and now I've [released it as a library](https://github.com/joelpurra/emulatetab) that uses [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

> [EmulateTab](https://github.com/joelpurra/emulatetab): A jQuery plugin to emulate tabbing between elements on a page.

You can [see how it works in the demo](http://joelpurra.github.com/emulatetab/example/demo.html).

```js
if (myTextHasBeenFilledWithText) {
  // Tab to the next input after #my-text-input
  $("#my-text-input").emulateTab();
}
```