# keydown event does not fire correctly using jQuery trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Please consider this code:

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" value="1111111111" id="TextBox1" />
<br />
<input name="TextBox2" type="text" value="222222222" id="TextBox2" />
<br />
<input name="TextBox3" type="text" value="3333333333" id="TextBox3" />
<br />
<input name="TextBox4" type="text" value="4444444444" id="TextBox4" />
<br />
<select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
<input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" />
<label for="CheckBox1">nima</label>
<br />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
```

and javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 9; // # Some key code value
            e.keyCode = 9;
            $("#TextBox1").trigger(e);
        });

        $("#TextBox1").on("keydown", function (e) {
            alert(e.keyCode);
        });
    });
```

the problem is when I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> on `TextBox1` I get message "9" for `keyCode` and `Textbox2` get focus. but when I press `Button1` I get message "9" for `keyCode` but `Textbox2` does not get focus. Where is my mistake? 
thanks

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yr0uab1s/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is that you're not actually handling the <kbd>TAB</kbd> press yourself, the browser is. Pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> whilst one interactive element has focus will inform the browser that you wish to have focus moved on to the next element in line (based on `tabIndex`).

Your button here isn't actually pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, it's passing the tab event to the `input` element.

If you wish to have this action blur the `#TextBox1` element and focus the `#TextBox2` element, you can make use of jQuery's `blur()` and `focus()` functions:

```
$("#TextBox1").on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 9) {
        $(this).blur();
        $('#TextBox2').focus();
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yr0uab1s/1/).

Comment: Thanks @James. the problem is I want to navigate between my controls using `Enter` key. I used a code for this but that code no longer works on IE 11.please see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438274/replace-keycode-in-ie-11

Comment: @Kerezo that's a different question. If you feel my post here has answered the question you've asked here, could you please accept it so that it can be closed? Thanks!