# Event.Keycode value assigning is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-11

Hi I have a search box when I search for some thing and hit enter i want to change it to tab and control go the button next to the search box. But it is not working in IE11. can any one please help me and tell me how can i assain a value to event.keycode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace keyCode in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438274/replace-keycode-in-ie-11)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is wrong. Don't change enter to tab. Tackle this problem by intercepting the enter key, set the focus on next element and cancel the event. jQuery solution:

Comment: i am not using jquerry any where its only just a jsp with javascript