# simple JS to convert Enter key in Tab key crossbrowser

Tags: javascript

How can i put this code to work in Chrome and Firefox ( a crossbrowser is perfectly )

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function convertEnterToTab() {
  if(event.keyCode==13) {
    event.keyCode = 9;
  }
}
document.onkeydown = convertEnterToTab;
```

Works only on IE

Comment: according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) enter is `13` everywhere and tab is `9` everywhere

Comment: Does this help at all?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438274/replace-keycode-in-ie-11