# Reuse default keyboard event handlers

Tags: events, vue.js, vue-events

I'm having form where I would like to be able to navigate through by using the arrow keys instead of <kbd>tab</kbd>.
Since there is already something which controls how the input should react when <kbd>tab</kbd> is pressed I would like to reuse this "default key event handler". However, I don't know how and I struggle to find something online.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<input type="text" @keydown.left.prevent="keydown.tab" />
```

Comment: this is how you can programmatically simulate a tab keydown event https://elgervanboxtel.nl/site/blog/simulate-keydown-event-with-javascript

Comment: I think only way is to implement this behavior in your code. Check this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803338/simulate-the-tab-key-function-in-javascript