# how to trigger previous tab(ctrl+pageup) key code in a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want to focus on my browser's previous tabs, so i want to trigger browser tab by triggering key-code. How to do this thing using key code.(and i don't find any keycode for "ctrl+pageup")

Answer (score 2):

That ain't possible.

You can't trigger OS/Browser functions like keypresses from JavaScript.

If this were possible, imagine the problems it would cause by:

- sites making you save stuff. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- sites making you close things. (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>)
- sites making you open new tabs. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- etc.

You can only [simulate these keypresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript) within the page's JS.

Comment: @ishanJain: I realise this isn't the answer you're looking for, but, not to brag or anything, it  is the only valid answer to this question. As such, please consider [Marking this as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).