# Fold ribbon on MS CRM 2011 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to fold ribbon in MS CRM 2011 using JavaScript?

How to achieve the same effect as then user double-clicks on ribbon?

Something like this (initial view is on the left, desirable — on the right):

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example or a screenshot? I didn't understand the effect yo want to simulate

Answer (score 2):

I don't how supported this would be but something to look into is:

[Control + Shift + 5](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/crm-2011-keyboard-shortcut-posters/) is a keyboard shortcut which opens and closes the ribbon.

Presumably there must be some event or function tided to that shortcut, so if you can dig around and find it you could try calling the code directly.

Or you could try simulating the key press - [Firing a Keyboard Event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript).