# How to programmatically input text with JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, dom, w3c

I'm trying to update the values of a text input with a close accuracy to DOM level 3 specification as possible.

`keydown`
`keypress`
`beforeInput`
(insertion)
`input`
`keyup`

Simply triggering the above events does not insert the character into the field, I believe this is standard across most browsers.

So I need to add the character to the `e.target`'s value just before dispatching the `input` event.

The input event looks (mostly) like this:

- bubbles: true
- cancelBubble: false
- cancelable: true
- charCode: 0
- currentTarget: null
- data: "TEXT I WANT TO PASTE"
- detail: 0
- eventPhase: 0
- keyCode: 0
- returnValue: true
- target: input
- type: "textInput"
- which: 0

There's no key location value, so I'm not sure where to add the `data` property to the target!

Is there any data in the keydown events I need to save, and then wait for an immediately following input event? Can I add the data to the input solely based on the information given by input event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firing a Keyboard Event in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 those answers are for firing the event. I know how to fire the evet, I'm trying to figure out the sequence that will add text to an input.

Comment: Hey Jackson, can we have some actual code please?

Comment: @JérémieAstori I later figured out that it's impossible for dispatching en event to modify the `value` of an input, so I'm doing it manually. Not sure why browsers work this way, however. If someone could explain it in an answer I'd accept :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Can I add the data to the input solely based on the information given by input event?

Not right now, but the [Editing task force](http://w3c.github.io/editing/) currently have [a draft spec](http://w3c.github.io/editing/input-events.html) that extends the `InputEvent` to allow this via `.targetRanges`.

As of April 2016 this is far from the implementation stage, as far as I can tell.

### Dispatching an event doesn't modify the value of an input

The current thinking, as described in [§ 3.10. Action versus occurrence](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#action-versus-occurance) of the DOM standard is that:

> An event signifies an occurrence, not an action. Phrased differently, it represents a notification from an algorithm and can be used to influence the future course of that algorithm (e.g., through invoking preventDefault()). **Events must not be used as actions or initiators that cause some algorithm to start running. That is not what they are for.**
>
> This is called out here specifically because previous iterations of the DOM had a concept of "default actions" associated with events that gave folks all the wrong ideas. Events do not represent or cause actions, they can only be used to influence an ongoing one.

This does mean there are a lot of missing APIs in the platform to initiate actions that the browser currently initiates automatically in response to the user's input...

Simulating keypresses is one of such missing features.