# trigger keyboard presses to reset browser zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger the `ctrl+0` in order to reset the browser zoom. If I do it manually and press `ctrl+0` then it resets the browser zoom.

Here is the code that I've tried:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
         e = $.Event("keypress");
         e.which = 48;
         e.ctrlKey = true;
         $(window).trigger(e);

        });
```

but it doesn't work. I tried to trigger the event on `$(document)` as-well but still no success.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript

Comment: you need to put event param it function--->`function(e)`

Comment: Use following Try it => <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#cats').click(function(){  

  
$("p").css('zoom' , 1.5);
  
 });
});
</script>
<title>Birman Cats</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>  Black Cat Superstitions</h1>
<div id="black">
<h2>  Folk Lore</h2>
<div id="cats">
<p><img src="http://s.w.org/style/images/wp-header-logo.png?1"/></p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the `ctrl+0` key combination is interpreted by the browser first and than sent to the event loop.
If you trigger it programmatic, it will go directly to the event loop.

In css there is a `zoom` property.

What you could probably do is:

- use a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers), to detect the browser zoom level
- set the `zoom` property to compensate for the browser zoom.

This way if the user has zoom 120%, you set from css `zoom` 80%.

---

Anyway, I advice against it because 99% of the time, the user wants/needs to zoom.

What it is better, would be to make your website look good even when zoomed, by using `em` units, percent values and maybe `media-queryes`

Comment: Hey!

I couldn't use the script the guy posted there since it returned with many errors.

to be honest, I don't really care what is the user current zoom level, I would like to reset it to be 100%, isn't there any way to do that?

Comment: No. The browser zoom comes before the css `zoom` property. Because of that you have no control over it. Strange that nothing from that entire answer worked for you.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 48) {
        // your code here..
    }
});

// if you wanna to resize (zoom in/out window)?
// your code goes here
$(window).resizeTo(w, H);

// if you wanna to set zoom attr?
// your code goes here
$('whatever').css('zoom', value);
```

Comment: that wasn't the problem to begin with. the problem was what code should I write? how do I reset the zoom..?

Comment: -_-||| use keypress you can fire the event?

Comment: "I tried to trigger the event on $(document) as-well but still no success." your question~~

Comment: what I meant with "no success" was that the browser didn't reset the zoom.

Comment: zoom in? or zoom out? or just simple css zoom attributes? and with your jquery code i realy hope keypress can work for you!

Answer (score -2):

Trust me, the best method is to use task scheduler to trigger a .vbs mentioned in
http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=76100.0

To reset zoom in browser, use the following vbs

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.SendKeys "^0"
```