# SimulateKeyPress"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, keypress, keycode

I am trying to make a javascript function with jquery that tricks the device using my html page that a keyboard key is being pressed when you click a button on the page, I just have one problem, when I click the button it doesn't work and when i look in the console in Google Chrome it says `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`, 
here is the javascript:

```
function simulateKeyPress(keycode) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
  evt.initKeyEvent ("keypress", true, true, window,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, keycode);
  var canceled = !body.dispatchEvent(evt); 
}
```

heres the html:

```
<div id="LeftArrow" onclick="simulateKeyPress(83)">
    <a href="#"><img src="PopularGamesImages/LeftArrow.jpg" width = "40px"/></a>
</div>
```

I would really apreciate it if anyone could help me with my problem,
Thanks.

Comment: According to the first comment in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5920206/1130908) answer, Chrome doesn't have the `initKeyEvent`, but does support `initKeyboardEvent`.  The answer looks like it was updated to support that as well.

Comment: i changed it but when i click the button and check the google chrome console it just says "Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined"