# Making the scrolling keys scroll the proper page element

Tags: javascript, scroll, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have a DIV in my page that is scrollable, while no other elements on the page are.  (The page layout is fixed with controls above and below the DIV itself.) I would like the arrow keys and page up/page down to scroll the DIV under all circumstances, but I cannot seem to do so unless the DIV actually has the focus.  There are other input fields in other DIVs which often have focus. I have tried capturing the arrow keys and page/up down 'keydown' event at the document level and simulating the same event directly ([using answers from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript)) to the DIV that needs to scroll, but no scrolling occurs.  I know the event is being dispatched because if I attach an event handler I see it, but for some reason it doesn't cause any scrolling.  I have also tried setting the "tabIndex" attribute of the DIV with no difference.

How can I designate a specific element to receive specific keys like this?  It is extremely user unfriendly to require a specific element to be focused for certain keys to work, when those keys only make sense for a single element on the page.  Having to constantly switch focus from another element to the scrollable area to scroll and back to enter data just isn't acceptable.

I have seen suggestions that scrolling can be simulated by other means, but I want to avoid that route because this doesn't always produce identical results, and I also want to generalize it to other kinds of key events and action besides scrolling.

Answer (score 6):

You can scroll any element by adjusting its [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) DOM property.

If you capture all the `keydown` events on the document and then decide on what action you want to take depending on the key pressed (use the `which` property of the `event` object) and maybe some other circumstances (inputs focused, controls checked etc.) you can easily scroll your `div`. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zh1dsewt/) for a simple demo.

Answer (score 0):

you can you keypress or keyDown events on the document and trigger actions on your DIV.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(document).on("keydown", handleKeyDown);

 function handleKeyDown(evt) {

var code = parseInt(evt.keyCode); // the key Code of the key which was pressed during the event /and parses it and returns a 'integer'.


    if(code == 38){ // 38 is the keycode for UP key on the keyboard
    alert("up");
    } else if(code == 40) // 40 is the keycode for down key on the keyboard.
    alert("down");
    }
    }
  });
```

and as explained in breif by Tadeáš Peták you can use the scrollTop DOM property to scroll any element, enjoy.