# Input fill with keypress simulation

Tags: javascript, dom-events, jscript

Let's say we have an input and we want to add some texts to it:

```
 <form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" id="thename" name="firstname">
</form>
```

The simple thing is to add value to input with classic `element.value...` .
But what if I want to add for example 'David' by simulating the `keypress` event?

I followed several approaches like this:

```
function simulateKeyEvent(character) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
  (evt.initKeyEvent || evt.initKeyboardEvent)("keypress", true, true, window,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, character.charCodeAt(0)) 
  var canceled = !body.dispatchEvent(evt);
  if(canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript) and read almost every solutions but they didn't work.

Note: I'm working in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome: Simulate keypress events on input text field using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219800/chrome-simulate-keypress-events-on-input-text-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to add text to the input, but make it seem as if its being typed by a ghost?

```
function typeToInput(id, str){
    var ctr = 0;
    var tmr = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById(id).value += str[ctr];
        ctr++;
        if(ctr >= str.length) clearInterval(tmr);
    }, 250);
}
```

though, you'll probably want to cancel the timer and clear the text if the input gets focus..

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50219991/289706).

For security reasons, you are not allowed to fire an event that will cause text to populate an input. See workarounds in the linked answer.