# Chrome: Simulate keypress events on input text field using javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a lot of contents on this in stack overflow but none seems to work for my case. I have an input text field and I want to simulate keypress event to fill the text field.

**Reason:** I am automating a lot of data entry task on a web interface which provides no API. Changing the input field using `.value` does not trigger the JS side (angular) of the interface. That is why I want to simulate keypress event.

First I tried this:

```
var inp = document.getElementById('rule-type');
inp.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'}));
```

Then I learned in Chrome the `key` and `code` stays as 0 and does not change in `KeyBoardEvent`.

So I created seperate event `ev = new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a', 'code': 'KeyA'})`

And then I dispatched again, the return statement is `true` but it does not change the input field.

The solution needs to be in pure javascript not jQuery.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why don't you set all the properties in the construction?

Comment: Why not to change the value

Comment: zero298, actually I did later and it still does not work when dispatched.
Sergey I have mentioned why.

Comment: Maybe try to explore Angular docs then? It should have some event triggers for similar purposes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dispatching keyboard event doesn't work in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163708/dispatching-keyboard-event-doesnt-work-in-javascript)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will not be able to fire an event that will cause text to populate an input.  See this snippet from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Auto-repeat_handling_prior_to_Gecko_5.0):

> Note: manually firing an event does not generate the default action
>   associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event
>   does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the
>   case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it
>   prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the
>   browser itself.

Thanks [@gforce301](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50219800/691711#comment-87457423)

Your best bet may be to set the value and **then** dispatch an event.

Comment: curious. why keydown? also your code is KeyA, key and keyCode is different. anyways after dispatching it wont change the text field.

Comment: @sjishan A manually fired keyboard event will never change the value of the input. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent note about half way down on manually fired events. This is for security reasons.

Comment: @gforce301 Good note.  I have updated my answer.  If you'd rather me delete my answer so that you could post that yourself, let me know.

Comment: thanks that was very informative. regarding your suggestion of setting the value and then dispatch the event. it wont work because since as soon as I set the value and then even if i do any manual data entry it does not work.

Comment: can this be done using UI events ? I tried this ev = new UIEvent('input', {'inputType': 'insertText', 'data':'a', isTrusted: true}) but given those parameters are read only it does not allow me to change

Comment: Thanks to zero298 and @gforce301. This answer saves my day!

Comment: @yaobin ikr I thought I was going crazy until I found this page!

Answer (score 27):

IMHO you're going about this all wrong. Angular is not "listening" to `keypress` or the like. It is listening to `change` and `input` events. See the example below. It does (admittedly it is simple) what you need.

```js
var iButton = document.getElementById('inputButton');
iButton.addEventListener('click', simulateInput);

var cButton = document.getElementById('changeButton');
cButton.addEventListener('click', simulateChange);

function simulateInput() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('name');
  var ev = new Event('input');
  
  inp.value =inp.value + 'a';
  inp.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

function simulateChange() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('name');
  var ev = new Event('change');
  
  inp.value = 'changed';
  inp.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
 
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input id="name" type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>

<button id="inputButton">I simulate the "input" event.</button>
<button id="changeButton">I simulate the "change" event.</button>
```

Comment: tried. didn't work. getting the same error. ApiException: [LocalizedErrorWrapper<LocalizedErrorWrapper<StringLengthError.TOO_SHORT @ name>>]  if I make any change using `.value` it just does not work anymore.

Comment: @sjishan I'm not an Angular expert. The example I gave is a minimal Angular app and as you can see the example works. Your error says: "StringLengthError.TOO_SHORT @ name". Maybe try putting in a string of a valid length?

Comment: it is of valid length. the reason it is saying too short is because it could not register the change. if i put the same string manually after refreshing the page it works fine. quite interestingly if i do not refresh and do manual entry after changing with `value` it still throws the same error.

Comment: @sjishan Also, what do you mean by "getting the same error"? Your post mentions nothing about getting an error. If the error is the problem then you should have asked about the error, instead of turning this into a [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: You're right its probably the XY Problem situation. I keep getting this LocalizedErrorWrapper<LocalizedErrorWrapper<StringLengthError.TOO_SHORT  if I change the value of the input text field using `.value` therefore I tried to use keyboard event to simulate user. i tried your solution its the same situation. that's why i said i am getting the same error.

Comment: @sjishan At this point I think you're going to have to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help.

Comment: Very good!!! nice solution

Answer (score 14):

To automate filling `<input>` and `<textarea>` values and automatically dispatch all needed events you need:

1. focus the input\textarea
2. run [document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) with `insertText` command

```js
let inputElement = document.getElementsById('rule-type');
inputElement.focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'input value');
```

With this method input\textarea value modification should be captured by all major frameworks including Angular an Vuejs. This modification will be processed by frameworks the same way as if user pressed "Paste" option in browser main menu.

Comment: This works flawlessly for me, but `document.execCommand` has been deprecated

Comment: I had been trying a long line of code for the last 2 days and found this one-line solution.