# How to fill input only by events?

Tags: javascript, html, events, input

I need to add some chars to input only by events, without access to input.value. My try:

HTML:

```
<input id="text" type="text">
```

JS:

```
// prepare     
let et = document.getElementById('text');
et.value = '';

// my try
et.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',  {key:'s', code:'KeyS', bubbles: true})); 
et.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {key:'s', code:'KeyS', bubbles: true}));
et.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input', {}));
et.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {key:'s', code:'KeyS', bubbles: true}));

// check
if (et.value === 's')
    alert ('success');
else 
    alert ('failure');
```

I have got 'failure' always. I need 'success')

Comment: You need to listen for the events before emitting them. `et.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => et.value += e.key); `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome: Simulate keypress events on input text field using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219800/chrome-simulate-keypress-events-on-input-text-field-using-javascript)

Comment: I can`t fill input by value like et.value = 's'. I have access to input.value only for setup or check.

Comment: "For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input." - Thank you! It`s an partial answer to my question.

Comment: As in the linked duplicate, an input will not fill due to manual firing of events. That will only trigger your attached listeners, not default behaviors.