# jQuery .each and trigger keypress to each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

So, I have a set of inputs and I need that when certain function is executed it loops all of the inputs and the triggers a keypress event. I do not need just to change the value, I need the keypress event because each input has a "onkeypress" event that I need it to respond to.

HTML:

```
<div id"myinputs">
<input name="name" onkeypress="return myfunction(this)" />
<input name="name1" onkeypress="return myfunction(this)" />
<input name="name2" onkeypress="return myfunction(this)" />
<input name="name3" onkeypress="return myfunction(this)" />
<input name="name4" onkeypress="return myfunction(this)" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 55;
e.keyCode = 55;
$("#myinputs").each(function(index, element)){
$(element).trigger(e);
});
```

I hope you guys can help! Thank you!

Comment: Why not just invoke the function that a keypress would invoke?

Comment: It's hard to explain, big code :/

Comment: use this:
$("input").each(function() {
    $(this).trigger("keypress");
  })

Comment: @zeropoint you can't do that without creating an event object that includes keycodes

Comment: I suspect you will need to do this with native event dispatcher if jQuery is not working. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript

Comment: create a similar demo

Comment: @zeropoint not working :(

Comment: @charlietfl I did. Checking now the question you sent

Comment: @zeropoint actually, it did work but passing "keyup" instead of "keypress". Thanks!