# Javascript input change

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events, contenteditable

Is it possible to change the input value of the keyboard?

For example:

You press the <kbd>a</kbd> key on your keyboard but `b` will be typed into the input element, instead of `a`.

You type `abc` but in the input element will be `def`.

I tried to capture the `keydown` event and then fire a `keydown` event with `CustomEvent` / `Event`, but It doesn't work for me. The event capturing is fine but when I create an other `keydown` event with the new `charCode` or `keyCode` the 'new' character won't be typed into the input.

So, is it possible to write something into an input element to the position of the caret, without using `value` property or any other methods which handle or modify the whole content of the input. So just insert or paste a letter.

JS

```
function keydown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var event = new Event('keydown');
    event.charCode = 65;
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="keydown(event)">
```

Probably, this is not possible in this way but I haven't any other idea so far...

Comment: @Gothdo: when did they stop allowing that?

Comment: @Gothdo ok, but are there any other possibilities for do this eg: paste text to the caret or to the selected area?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firing a Keyboard Event in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript)

Comment: @Gothdo: do any of the answers on that page work in chrome? i tried several just now with no luck... i used to have code that worked, and it stopped too....

Comment: @dandavis The top answer doesn't work for me in Chrome and Firefox too. The answer is five years old, so maybe it's obsolete now.

Comment: @dandavis [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19883789/3853934) is probably the most up-to-date answer. It turns out I was right that keyboard events can't be triggered with JavaScript.

Comment: i'm not ready to throw in the towel just yet. i had a `simKey(targ,kc)` util that worked well and don't see the harm it posed. maybe you're right about newer browsers, or maybe there's just a lot of stale docs out there. ok, i know there's a lot of stale docs, i was hoping you would find something that works in chrome...

Comment: @dandavis That kind of event simulation works well with `addEventListener` but doesn't result any insertion to the input. Just create an event which you ar able to listen to. The best solution, what I've found, was the `execCommand` below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do this with [`document.execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand):

```js
document.querySelector("input")
.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'b');
})
```

```html
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to get the cursor position when you type something. once you get the cursor position you can replace the character and set the text back to the text box. let me know you want code to put the cursor back to the location where it replaced the character.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getLocation(ctrl)
{
    var position = 0;

    if (document.selection) {

        ctrl.focus ();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange ();

        sel.moveStart ('character', -ctrl.value.length);

        position = Sel.text.length;
    }
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
        position = ctrl.selectionStart;

    alert (position);
}

</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="getLocation(this);"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this solution, but if I replace the character I must change the whole value