# Programmatically keypress on a focused drop-down element without Jquery

Tags: javascript, keypress, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to press enter (programmatically) on a drop down element. I CANNOT USE JQUERY. 
The drop down is already in focus, I just want to click enter to open it. 
Any ideas how it can be achieved? 
Here's my HTML:

```
<select class="test">
  <option value="1">item1</option>
  <option value="2">item2</option>
  <option value="3">item3</option>
  <option value="4">item4</option>
  <option value="5">item5</option>
  <option value="6">item6</option>
</select>
```

And the JS that got the element focused:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].focus();
```

Comment: Here's a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript

Comment: Better off using a `<select>` replacement script. Very hard to work with them programmatically cross browser

Comment: There is no event that will do what you want.

Comment: @charlietfl I can't. have to be <select>. I'm creating a chrome extension that injects code to another page that uses this element, and I need to change it by opening it.

Answer (score 0):

var element = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
element.onclick.apply(element);