# Simulate spacebar press with touchevent in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, events, touch, simulate

I'm trying to port a game on Android and in the game the player press space to jump and I can't find any working solution to simulate a spacebar event when a user touch the screen

Here's the code I've found until now :

```
/**
 * Keep track of the spacebar events
 */
var KEY_CODES = {
  32: 'space'
};
var KEY_STATUS = {};
for (var code in KEY_CODES) {
  if (KEY_CODES.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
     KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[code]] = false;
  }
}
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
  if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
    e.preventDefault();
    KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = true;
  }
};
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
  if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
    e.preventDefault();
    KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = false;
  }
};
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
  document.onkeydown({ keyCode: 32 });
});
document.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
  document.onkeyup({ keyCode: 32 });
});
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work...

And then this :

```
// jump higher if the space bar is continually pressed
if (KEY_STATUS.space && jumpCounter) {
  player.dy = player.jumpDy;
}
```

Above is all the code that use the space bar event

[Full Game code](http://pastebin.com/6yTDTdGR)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the keyCode from the event, try writing 
`({ e.keyCode: 32});`

Answer (score 1):

you can define a handler and then wrap the jump function. fire it with the event needed. Ex:

```
function jump(keyEvent) { /* code to jump*/}
```

this is a bad idea but it can work for you. This way you dont have to worry about the preventDefault method.

```
function jumpHandler(e) { e.keyCode = 32; jump(e) /*object to simulate the keydown event object*/ }
```

to avoid the manipulation of event object you could pass an empty function in the same way yo are passing the keyCode property. But you will lose the preventDefault functionality.

```
function jumpHandler() { jump({keyCode:32, preventDefault: function(){}}) /*object to simulate the keydown event object*/ }

document.addEventListener('touchstart', jumpHandler);
document.onKeydown = jump // here just the reference to the handler
```

Some times returnig false at the end of function can have the same behavior of preventDefault, I´m telling you this just whether you want to return false instead of calling preventDefault.

:)

Comment: In the /* code to jum*/ I can the full jump code ? It's :    if (KEY_STATUS.space && player.dy === 0 && !player.isJumping) {
      player.isJumping = true;
      player.dy = player.jumpDy;
      jumpCounter = 12;
      assetLoader.sounds.jump.play();
    }

Comment: yes, you can put all you need into the jump function. Just be sure that you provide all needed for the required context.

Comment: I´m testing the fragment of code i wrote and it is working. do you have your game uploaded in some place where i can test it?...

Comment: I'm testing in your site and it is working too. I just injected my code and test it with devtool in order to simulate touch events. It works but the mandarine is jumping like crazy. I had to comment the e.preventDefaultt because our fake object does not have this method, I will edit my answer to give aditional idea. To prevent this you have to simulate the keyup event too in the same way.

Comment: I might have wroted it all wrong since it doesn't work for me... Here's the piece of script I wrote with yours. Paste link : http://pastebin.com/m4LekmpK