# trigger ctrl+s event when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button. Now when I click on the button the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> will be pressed or triggered in jquery or javascript. How to do that?

I have tried:

```
$("#Save").click(function() {
    var e = $.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 115, ctrlKey:true} );
    $("body").trigger(e);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want the user to save the HTML, you could link to the server and have the server send a content disposition header which downloads the file.

Comment: But i want to create event ctrl+s on button click not ant button "PRESS".

Comment: For what purpose? Ctrl+s on Windows does something different to Ctrl+s on a Mac.

Comment: I am opening third party site in iframe and when user click on save the ctrl+s event genrate and image save in folder so i want in cirl+s event in javascript or jquery @RyanJenkin

Comment: your event is work check your query $("body")

Comment: this code nothing do in my windows machine @K.Angel7