# Trigger Keyup Event in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve the equivalent of the jQuery (below) written in plain JavaScript:

```
$('input[name=\"myelementname\"]').keyup();
```

I haven't been able to find a simple solution thus far. Any ideas?

Comment: [Firing a Keyboard Event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you have to create a new Event:

```
let keyupEvent = new Event('keyup');
```

And then use `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`:

```
// here we use Array.from() to convert the NodeList
// returned from the document.getElementsByNames...
// call into an Array:
Array.from(

  // document.getElementsByName() retrieves all the
  // elements on the page with the supplied name:
  document.getElementsByName('myelementname')

// we iterate over that Array using Array.prototype.forEach():
).forEach(

  // here we use an Arrow function, the 'input' is a reference
  // to the current element (regardless of element-type, since
  // we selected by name) of the Array-element of the Array
  // over which we're iterating.

  // we trigger the named event (using a cached copy of that
  // created Event) on the element:
  input => input.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent)
);
```

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Event constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event).
- [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).

Bibliography:

- "[Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)," (MDN)