# how to map enter key to tab key in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

## Map enter key to tab key

i want to focus on next html element on enter key same as that of tab.
i tried following code but its not working.
i don't want to write any code i just want to map enter key to tab.

```
 dockeyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.keyCode = 9;
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", this.doc_keyUp, false);
  }
```

on above code i get error that keycode is readonly property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firing a Keyboard Event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript)

Comment: do you need to focus on next element while enter check this code once,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tcgeqb