# How do I trigger an event like keyup with a specified keycode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to test in jasmine and need to trigger a keyup event with a specified keycode (enter in my case). When i try this

```
document.getElementById('title').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});
var e = $.Event("keyup", {keyCode: 64});
$('title').trigger(e);
```

the event is not being triggered, although when I do manually set focus on it and press it is being triggered

but when i try this

```
$('title').on('keyup', function(e){
     e.currentTarget.style.color = 'red';
     console.log(e.keyCode);
});

var e = $.Event("keyup", {keyCode: 64});
$('title').trigger(e);
```

it is being triggered. I dont understand why one is not working and the other one is

Comment: First line of the `.trigger()` doc: "Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs."

Comment: missing the `event` parameter: `...('keyup', function(e){`

Comment: i dont understand, can you clarify

Comment: first line should be: `document.getElementById('title').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){`

Comment: ohh wow how did i miss that, okay thanks

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: wait its still not working

Comment: Again: `.trigger()` only triggers event listeners that were added using a jQuery function. It won't trigger listeners added using `addEventListener`

Comment: ahhh that makes sense, but then how do i trigger a event added using addEventListener

Comment: Did you try googling it? This is the second result for me when I google "trigger a event added using addEventListener": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: yes, can't find one that has example with specified keycode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Also dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use addEventListener don't use trigger, use dispatchEvent :

```
document.getElementById("q").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { 'keyCode': 65 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

.trigger() only works when the event handler is attached using jquery. It doesn't work on native event listeners.

In the second case, you're attaching with $(..).on So jquery will trigger that event. 
Native Event Listener won't work here. You can use dispatchEvent

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {keyCode: 64});

document.getElementById('title').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});

document.getElementById('title').dispatchEvent(event);
```

Check here for more info
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: its logging undefined

Comment: Give it a try now.